# ModuleNotFoundError for psychopy

Tags: python, psychopy

I’m new to Python and Psychopy. I’ve tried running the following:

```
print("foo")
from psychopy import visual, core, gui, event
print("bar")
```

Both from the command line and inside the Spyder IDE, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from psychopy import visual, core, gui, event
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psychopy'
```

System specs: macOS High Sierra v.10.13.4, Macbook Air

Python version: Python 3.7.1 (python -V)

I’ve installed the following dependencies: wxPython, pyo, and the ones in the following code:

```
pip install numpy scipy matplotlib pandas pyopengl pyglet pillow 
moviepy lxml openpyxl xlrd configobj pyyaml gevent greenlet 
msgpack-python psutil tables requests[security] pyosf cffi 
pysoundcard pysoundfile seaborn psychopy_ext python-bidi psychopy
pip install pyserial pyparallel egi iolabs
pip install pytest coverage sphinx

pip install pyobjc-core pyobjc-framework-Quartz
```

I also tried using pip3.  iolabs was not able to install but the link below seems to state it is optional.

All from [this](https://www.psychopy.org/installation.html) resource. It seemed to run without a hitch (aside from some that didn’t like Spyder, but I ran it on the command line as well as Spyder, so that shouldn’t be a problem).

Any suggestions?

Comment: for python3 you need to run `pip3` instead of `pip` if you also have python2 installed on your system

Comment: @liamhawkins Not necessarily.

Comment: I will try that.

Comment: That did not work, I will add it to the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to create a virtual environment. 
Can you try the following command lines in your terminal?:

`conda create -n psychopy  python=3.6  anaconda` # it creates a virtual env named psychopy

`source activate psychopy` # it activates this virtual environment

`pip install psychopy` # it installs psychopy lib in the virtual environment.

Then, to try the used-case here again, type:

`python` # it opens python

`>>> from psychopy import visual, core, gui, event`

It should work.

Comment: I'm trying now.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the Python interpreter that Spyder is pointing to is a different one to the python installation that received the `pip install` command.

Rather than calling `pip install` which doesn't tell you which python is used, it's now recommended that you use:

```
python -m pip install psychopy
```

so that you can choose any particular python as your executable. For Spyder you'd also have to check which python executable it's pointing to.

Comment: Shouldn't trying it in the command line have ruled that out as the problem?

Comment: Running in the command line takes care of the spyder aspect but doesn't help you to know where the pip command points. If you have 2 Pythons, you probably have 2 pips
BUT I just realised I typed the command in wrong for what you need to do to specify which Python is used (now edited)

Comment: I did try using pip3 as well as another poster suggested.  Shouldn't that have removed the ambiguity?

Comment: No, using pip3 doesn't remove the ambiguity. You can have two versions of Python 3 installed (maybe a 3.7 and a 3.6). Which one does pip3 point to now?